# Ionic : npm test command hangs in azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am creating a pipeline for my ionic project (desktop, android, and iOS): a `job` for each platform.

the first job is as follows:

```
jobs:

- job: Build_Ionic

  pool:
    vmImage: 'macos-latest'

  steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
     versionSpec: '12.0.x'
     checkLatest: true
    displayName: 'install NodeJS'

  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
     script: |
      npm install
      npm test --watch=false

  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
      includeRootFolder: true
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
      replaceExistingArchive: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/'
      artifact: 'dist'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

everything works fine till the script `npm test --watch=false`, where it hangs.
the output of this script is :

```
26 08 2020 10:02:36.978:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
26 08 2020 10:02:36.984:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v5.0.9 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
26 08 2020 10:02:36.984:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
26 08 2020 10:02:36.987:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
26 08 2020 10:02:42.476:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
26 08 2020 10:02:42.689:INFO [Chrome 84.0.4147.135 (Mac OS 10.15.6)]: Connected on socket UU2YzJ0dLFGblvfdAAAA with id 31198897
Chrome 84.0.4147.135 (Mac OS 10.15.6): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
WARN: ''mobile-app-root' is not a known element:
1. If 'mobile-app-root' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mobile-app-root' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
Chrome 84.0.4147.135 (Mac OS 10.15.6): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
WARN: ''mobile-app-root' is not a known element:
1. If 'mobile-app-root' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mobile-app-root' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
Chrome 84.0.4147.135 (Mac OS 10.15.6): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.06 secs)
Chrome 84.0.4147.135 (Mac OS 10.15.6): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.081 secs / 0.06 secs)
TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS
```

So I guess there are no issues in my test. Any ideas why it freezes on this command?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar issue. And it was fixed by set the `singleRun` to `true` in karma.conf.js. If true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits. The value is false by default if not set explicitly.

See below:

```
autoWatch: false,
singleRun: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with getting my `jest` tests to run.  They ran fine locally, but not in Azure Pipelines.  I ended up discovering that there was a hanging process that was never closed after my tests were done causing it to freeze.

I used the command `jest ./tests --detectOpenHandles` to find the process and after I made sure the process was closed, the tests ran fine in Azure.